# Using numpy to initialize empty array with data type object

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Can I use numpy to create an array that can hold up to 12 objects?? I have an object like `app.feOutput` and I need 12 variables initialized with that object.

I hope someone can help me. Just new to python stuff especially handling objects.

Comment: Do you mean you want to initialize an empty array and assign objects later? looking for `np.empty((12,), dtype=object)` maybe?

Comment: Object dtype arrays are a bit advanced for Python beginners.  Why aren't you using a list?

Comment: Assigning one object to all 12 slots of an object dtype array will have the same problem as making a list with 12 references to that object.

Comment: @Ehsan Thank you for the info. Still new to the StackOverflow community.

Comment: @hpaulj it was referred to me by my friend to use it for handling larger quantity of data but I'll take note on what you mention. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize an empty array like this:

```
a = np.empty((12,), dtype=object)
```

And later you can assign your desired objects to its element:

```
a[i] = obj_i
```